# Why does reshaping my data completely change the behaviour of a fully connected neural network in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I would love some insight on this. I'm working on a regression problem in Keras with a simple neural network. I have train and test data, training data consists of 33230 samples with 20020 features (which is a ton of features for this amount of data, but that's another story - the features are just various measurements).  Test set is 8308 samples with same number of features. My data is in a pandas dataframe, and I convert it into numpy arrays which seem to look as expected:

```
X_train = np.array(X_train_df)
X_train.shape

(33230, 20020)

X_test = np.array(X_test_df)
X_test.shape

(8308, 20020)
```

If I pass this into the following fully connected model, it trains very quickly, and produces terrible results on the test set:

Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation="relu", input_shape=(20020,)))
model.add(Dense(300, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
```

Fit:

```
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, validation_data=(X_test,  y_test), batch_size=128, shuffle=True, epochs=100)
```

Results after 5 epochs (doesn't change substantially after this, training loss goes down, validation loss shoots up):

```
Train on 33230 samples, validate on 8308 samples
Epoch 1/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 11s 322us/sample - loss: 217.6460 - mean_absolute_error: 9.6896 - val_loss: 92.2517 - val_mean_absolute_error: 7.6400
Epoch 2/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 10s 308us/sample - loss: 70.0501 - mean_absolute_error: 7.0170 - val_loss: 90.1813 - val_mean_absolute_error: 7.5721
Epoch 3/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 10s 309us/sample - loss: 62.5253 - mean_absolute_error: 6.6401 - val_loss: 104.1333 - val_mean_absolute_error: 8.0131
Epoch 4/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 11s 335us/sample - loss: 55.6250 - mean_absolute_error: 6.2346 - val_loss: 142.8665 - val_mean_absolute_error: 9.3112
Epoch 5/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 10s 311us/sample - loss: 51.7378 - mean_absolute_error: 5.9570 - val_loss: 208.8995 - val_mean_absolute_error: 11.4158
```

However if I reshape the data:

```
X_test = X_test.reshape(8308, 20020, 1)
X_train = X_train.reshape(33230, 20020, 1)
```

And then use the same model with a Flatten() after the first layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation="relu", input_shape=(20020,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(300, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
```

Then my results look very different, and much better:

```
Train on 33230 samples, validate on 8308 samples
Epoch 1/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 1117s 34ms/sample - loss: 112.4860 - mean_absolute_error: 7.5939 - val_loss: 59.3871 - val_mean_absolute_error: 6.2453
Epoch 2/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 1112s 33ms/sample - loss: 4.7877 - mean_absolute_error: 1.6323 - val_loss: 23.8041 - val_mean_absolute_error: 3.8226
Epoch 3/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 1116s 34ms/sample - loss: 2.3945 - mean_absolute_error: 1.1755 - val_loss: 14.9597 - val_mean_absolute_error: 2.8702
Epoch 4/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 1113s 33ms/sample - loss: 1.5722 - mean_absolute_error: 0.9616 - val_loss: 15.0566 - val_mean_absolute_error: 2.9075
Epoch 5/100
33230/33230 [==============================] - 1117s 34ms/sample - loss: 1.4161 - mean_absolute_error: 0.9179 - val_loss: 11.5235 - val_mean_absolute_error: 2.4781
```

It also takes 1000x times longer, but performs well on the test set. I don't understand why this happens. Can someone shed light on this? I'm guessing I'm missing something really basic, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good question. First of all you will have to understand how the network actually work. `Dense` layer is a fully conected layer so each neuron will have a connection with the previous layer's neuron. Now your networks Performance that you have mentioned that it is `1000x` time slower is nothing to do with your training data, but with your network. Your second network is so big that I was unable to fit it in my RAM as well as not in Google Colab. So for demonstration purposes I will take that your training data is is of `(500, 100)` shape.

For the First network that you posted taking the above mentioned shape your model network looks something like below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation="relu", input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(Dense(300, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])


Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 300)               30300     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 300)               90300     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 100)               30100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 150,801
Trainable params: 150,801
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Take a note of the Total params, it is `150,801`.
Now if we take your second example.

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(300, activation="relu", input_shape=(100,1)))
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(300, activation="relu"))
model1.add(Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 100, 300)          600       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 30000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 300)               9000300   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 100)               30100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 9,031,101
Trainable params: 9,031,101
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Your total params increases to `9,031,101`. You can image when you use your actual data that has length `20020`. Your model increases like anything and I was even unable to fit that model in my RAM.

So to conclude, your second model has huge number of parameters compared to first model. This is the reason for slow training and better performance may be? more parameters makes the learning better. Can't say what makes it better without actually looking at your data. But more parameters can contribute to better performance.

Note: If you remove the `Flatten` layer your network paramters will decrease, here is the example.

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(300, activation="relu", input_shape=(100,1)))
model1.add(Dense(300, activation="relu"))
model1.add(Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 100, 300)          600       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 100, 300)          90300     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 100, 100)          30100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 100, 1)            101       
=================================================================
Total params: 121,101
Trainable params: 121,101
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I hope my answer helped you understand what is hapening and what is the difference between two models.

**UPDATE : 20/07**
For your comment, I thought it is better to update the answer for more clarity. Your question is -- **how does the number of parameters relate to the shape of the network?**

To be honest I do not clearly understand what you mean by this. I will still try to answer it. The more layers or neurons you add increases the network and the number of trainable parameters.

So your actual issue is why does the layer `Flatten` increases you parameter. For that you need to understand how are parameters calculated.

```
model.add(Dense(300, activation="relu", input_shape=(100,)))
```

Consider this is your first layer the number of parameters will be `units *(input_size + 1)` that comes to `30300`. Now when you add the `Flatten` layer, this actually does not increase your parameter by itself, but the output of the `Flatten` layer is input to the following layer. So consider the following example.

```
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 30000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 300)               9000300   
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here you can see that the output size of the `Flatten` layer is `30000`. Now considering the above formula you can see `300 *(30000 + 1)` will result in `9000300` parameters which is a huge deal in itself. More number of parameters can help to learn more features and might help to achieve better results. But it always depends on the data, you will have to experiment with it.

I hope the above explainations might have cleared your doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would have a follow-up question though: how does the number of parameters relate to the shape of the network? For example, I can increase the number of parameters in the first, non-flattened and non-reshaped example to be similar to the second by adding an arbitrary number of neurons to one of the hidden layers (eg. 300000 neurons instead of 300), but in this case the test case behaves the same, ie. increasing loss from first epoch. How does flattening after the first layer change the network behaviour?

Comment: If the solution presented above worked for you, I will encourage you to upvote it so that others can benefit from it. Thank you.